# Hide column for table using antd

Tags: antd

How can we hide a column from the table for displaying in frontend which already exists in the array for using ant design table?

For example, I have a column called ID in my array object, but no need to show in the table view, it should be kept in the JSON list itself for some reference purpose.

[Fiddle link](https://codesandbox.io/s/1oyyx5981j) - In this example I don't want to show the ID column in the table, but I have used the ID for some reference like a row delete.

Comment: Just omit this column in the `columns` field

Comment: In my scenario I can't, its kept for some reference.

Comment: Generally, the @awesoon suggestion is correct. Jaison, which reference you need to keep? Share the codebase so we can understand the particular issue.

Comment: @Alex Fiddle link added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Maktel suggestion is correct: you can easily implement what you want by defining [`render` in column](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) (note that there is no `dataIndex`):

```
let columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  },
  {
    title: "Action",
    key: "action",
    render: (row) => {
      let api = "/api/v1/row/delete/";
      //this ID be sued for POST delete row like a API below
      api = api + row.id;
      return <span onClick={() => { alert(api);}}>
         Delete
      </span >

    }
  }
];

let data = [
  {
    id: 312,
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
  },
  {
    id: 1564,
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
  }
];

const App = () => <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
```

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake, I was misunderstood for @awesoon's comment.

Answer (score 32):

Here is how I did it. The concept is the same, which is to remove (filter out) the column from the array.

Add a property "hidden" to the column object, then filter it out.

```js
let columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  },
  {
    title: "Action",
    key: "action",
    dataIndex: "action",
    hidden: true
  }
].filter(item => !item.hidden);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you already have the code generating your columns, a much simpler option than implementing a custom render method to hide a column is simply to filter it out of your completed columns list, e.g.:

```
let columns = [
  {
    title: "Id",
    dataIndex: "id",
    key: "id"
  },
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  }
];

return columns.filter(col => col.dataIndex !== 'id');
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

You can override header and body render methods as following assuming your column has visible property.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    const renderBody = (props, columns) => {
      return (
        <tr className={props.className}>
          {columns.map((item, idx) => {
            if (item.visible) {
              return props.children[idx]
            }
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    }

    const renderHeader = (props, columns) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          {columns.map((item, idx) => {
            if (item.visible)
              return props.children[idx];
          })};
        </tr>
      );
    }

    const columns = [{
      title: 'col1',
      dataIndex: 'col1',
      visible: true
    }, {
      title: 'col2',
      dataIndex: 'col2',
      visible: false
    }]

    return (
      <Table
        rowKey="key"
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data.list || []}
        components={{
          header: {
            row: (props) => renderHeader(props, columns)
          },
          body: {
            row: (props) => renderBody(props, columns)
          },
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me .... until I tried to enable `rowSelection` on the Table.

Answer (score 1):

`Table`'s prop `columns` is used to control what columns will be rendered by the table, but has no influence over shape of the data used as `dataSource`. Omitting a column does not remove its value from `dataSource` and you can still reference it for example in `render` property of the column (e.g. to generate a callback).

Sample code (*note that `hiddenValue` is not directly referenced by `dataIndex` property of any column and could be omitted altogether*):

```js
const TableWithHiddenColumn = () => {
    const dataSource = [
        { renderedValue: 'foo', hiddenValue: 'id_1' },
        { renderedValue: 'bar', hiddenValue: 'id_2' },
        { renderedValue: 'biz', hiddenValue: 'id_3' },
    ];

    const columns = [
        { title: 'Visible column', dataIndex: 'renderedValue', key: 'renderedValue' },
        {
            title: 'Action',
            key: 'action',
            render: (record) => (
                <Button
                    onClick={() => {
                        console.log(record.hiddenValue);
                    }}
                >
                    {record.hiddenValue}
                </Button>
            ),
        },
    ];

    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />;
};
```

Result:

[image: rendered result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the replay, question updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old question and has many answer but I want to share another solution that I just applied.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  },
  ...(!hideLast ?
    [
      {
        title: "Action",
        key: "action",
        dataIndex: "action",
        hidden: true
      }
    ]
    :
    []
  )
];
```

Comment: Instead of using `[]` after `?`, I used the normal json format. i.e. `{}` like ```(!hideLast ? { title: "Action", key: "action", dataIndex: "action"} :
    {}
  )```

Comment: @biniam If hideLast is true then your code adds `{}` to the last. That will increase length of array.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add the `...` before the parenthesis and your code wasn't working for me. That's why I tried changing it. Your suggestion works!

Answer (score 0):

To build on previous answers and add one that also plays nicer with typescript:

```
const showOptionalColumn = false; // or however you determine it;

const columns: TableProps<TItem>["columns"] = [
  showOptionalColumn && {
    title: "Id",
    dataIndex: "id",
    key: "id"
  },
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address"
  }
].filter(Boolean); // filters out any falsy values
```