# antd table - idiomatic way to programatically filter on a field that is not mapped to a coiumn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I can programatically tell a `antd` table to filter, e.g.

```
{
   title: "Status",
   dataIndex: "Status",
   key: "Status",
   filteredValue: myAllowedFoos,
   onFilter: (value, record) => record.Foo === value,
   filter: true,
 },
```

but how to do this filtering for **other fields in the record which are not mapped to `antd` columns** ?

---

I know you have hide/show a whole column as in [Ant Design for React : Show/Hide particular column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751933/ant-design-for-react-show-hide-particular-column) but that is not what I want as I want to have programmatic filters on them.

There seems at least 2 options :

1. CSS
2. Overide table `render()`

Re., CSS, I have read at

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100815/449347
  CSS workarounds (but I haven't found how to update the header cell but I can hide the row cells using https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/19335 )

Re., Override render is described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62016452/449347

Both options seem a bit hacky ?
Is there a better way ?