# How to hide an antd table column via CSS?

Tags: css, antd

How to use CSS to hide a particular column(s)  of a antd table ?

This is one possible approach mentioned in another question I asked at [antd table - how to programatically filter on a field that is not mapped to a coiumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780870/antd-table-how-to-programatically-filter-on-a-field-that-is-not-mapped-to-a-co)